# I'm getting an invalid Json, response will not trigger responde to this code. Any suggestions?

Tags: json

```
{
  "output": {
    "ssml": "At this point, would you like to learn <mark name="anim 13_Arm_RtPointMe 1.0"/>more about me, as well as some facts about cancer, or would <mark name="anim 23_Arm_RtPalmupLow 1.0"/>you prefer to go straight to answering questions. You can return to hear my story and facts about cancer at any time by pressing the Genie Shares button.",
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "At this point, would you like to learn more about me, as well as some facts about cancer, or would you prefer to go straight to answering questions. You can return to hear my story and facts about cancer at any time by pressing the “Genie Shares” button."
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    },
    "input_options": [
      "Yes",
      "No"
    ],
    "enable_microphone": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the quotes around "Genie Shares". Try using single quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes within a value must be escaped with `\`.

Replace all `"` within `ssml` with `\"`.